# find path distance using set of points in the path

Tags: math, geometry, distance

I have a set of coordinates long and lat represent a path.

```
coordinates = [
    [60, 58],
    [63, 67],
    [69, 82],
    [74, 75],
    [85, 73]
...
];
```

How can I calculate the path distance in meters

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question is not clear. Does the path begin at the first point and end at the last point? Is each sub-path between consecutive points a straight line segment? Are these points on the surface of the Earth (longitude and latitude) or on a Euclidean plane? If on the earth, is each sub-path an arc over the surface of the earth or a straight line segment through the interior of the earth? Are the units for those numbers degrees or something else? Please clarify. Finally, what work have you done on this problem, and just where are you stuck?

Comment: Do you mean the path length ? (I.e. sum of Euclidean distances)

Comment: @RoryDaulton yes the first point is the path begins and the last is the end. The points are longitude and latitude. let say its a vehicle moving in a selected range and every second it sends its location. the path not closed (the last location not the begin location)

Comment: You have answered some questions but not all. I think I can assume that the unit is degrees and you want distances over the earth's surface and you want line-segment distances as a lower bound on the actual distance (which cannot be precisely determined). Though coordinates each second will not give those values. But you left out some very important things--what work have you done on this problem, and just where are you stuck? Do you know how to find the geographical distance between two points? Did you do a web search on that topic?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I found Haversine formula to calculate the geographical distance between two points. can I used the accumulate distance between every sequence point to find the full distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said in a comment that you can find the distance over the surface of the earth between two points given by longitude and latitude. Let's say you have a function that can do this that can be called with `earth_distance(pt1, pt2)`. You can use Python to add all the distances between consecutive points with

```
total_distance = sum(earth_distance(pt1, pt2)
                     for pt1, pt2 in zip(coordinates, coordinates[1:]))
```

That formula uses the built-in `zip` function to get pairs of points, the slice `[1:]` to mean that pairs of points are consecutive points in your `coordinates` list, your `earth_distance` function to calculate the distance between two points, and `sum` to add them all together. This is a pythonic way to solve your problem.

Here is a way that is more similar to how other languages would do this, though still in Python.

```
total_distance = 0
pt2 = coordinates[0]
for ndx in range(1, len(coordinates)-1):
    pt1 = pt2
    pt2 = coordinates[ndx]
    total_distance += earth_distance(pt1, pt2)
```

or this:

```
total_distance = 0
for ndx in range(1, len(coordinates)-1):
    pt1 = coordinates[ndx - 1]
    pt2 = coordinates[ndx]
    total_distance += earth_distance(pt1, pt2)
```